# Ubuntu Studio 20.04 on a iMac Mid-2010

Tags: system-installation, mac, macosx, ubuntu-studio

I'm a Linux user for a long time, but I stayed away since Ubuntu Netbook Edition. I've been using iMac Mid-2010 for the last 10 years, and since I'm not planning on giving my kidneys for an up-to-date machine, and since the one I have serves me well enough, I would like to install Ubuntu Studio 20.04. I'm a podcaster and I'm beginning to edit videos for online courses.

My problem is this: I burnt the .iso on a DVD, and my iMac doesn't recognize it (I'm using an external DVD drive because the original just died). I tried three times to flash the image into an USB flash drive, but when I boot it and choose to run Ubuntu from the flash drive (safe graphics or not), I get a dark screen, forcing me to restart my computer.

As I said, I have an iMac 21.5", mid 2010; Intel i3 3.06GHz, 4GB 1333 MHz DDR3; 500GB HD; ATI Radeon HD 4670 256MB.

Can anyone help me, please?

**June 29, edited**: I managed to install Ubuntu Studio 20.04. However, after installation, the required reboot results in a black screen. The iMac is running, but the screen doesn't show anything.

Comment: Yes, I verified. ISO integrity, my media it's valid since I used it before to put Lubuntu in a HP Mini, and I already checked documentation.

Comment: I think there's a problem with your GPU.It might not be supported by the newer builtin amdgpu drivers in linux.Try downloading [this driver](https://www.amd.com/en/support/graphics/amd-radeon-hd/ati-radeon-hd-4000-series/ati-radeon-hd-4670) that was released exactly for your GPU(i.e ATI Radeon HD 4670) and please read the [installation manual](https://www.amd.com/en/support/kb/faq/amdgpupro-install)

Comment: But if you still have problems , you can consider using an older ubuntu release,because unfortunately that AMDGPUPRO driver was built for **Xorg 6.9 , Xserver 1.12 and Kernel version up to 3.4**.To put that into perspective, for example ubuntu 20.04 uses kernel 5.x

Answer (score 1):

I have a mid 2009 iMac 27"
I installed Ubuntu 20.x
I ran into similar issues but followed these steps and now works fine:

After installation, I went into LiveCD mode (try Ubuntu). Its the only way to fix permanently (ie not during startup everytime). But it's a bit tricky when you have to fix this when running from a Live CD. Essentially the idea is to mount the installed Linux from within the LiveCD. I did that, and it helped me a lot. So here are the steps:

- Run from the Live CD, and either install Ubuntu or move on if already done
- Check your installed partition with the command "gparted". It opens a Window telling you where you installed Ubuntu. In my case it was /dev/sda2 which contained an ext4 partition.
- Mount the partition: sudo mount /dev/sdXY /mnt
  Then mount/bind the directories Grub needs to access like this:

```
sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev &&
sudo mount --bind /dev/pts /mnt/dev/pts &&
sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc &&
sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
```

- Then move on to this environment using chroot

```
sudo chroot /mnt
```

- You should now be able to edit /etc/default/grub now.

```
sudo vi /etc/default/grub
```

and change the line

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nomodeset"
```

PS: I found it very useful to also remove quiet and splash so I could see something moving on behind the scenes.

- The only thing left for me was update-grub

```
sudo update-grub
```

Rebooted and the new settings where in place. With the "nomodeset" option I was able to boot Ubuntu and Lubuntu from a MacBook Pro harddisk.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems with the black / blank screen.  From what I can remember of my previous research over a year ago, this seems to stem from the lack of user-space mode-setting support (UMS) for the old Radeon HD 4670 GPU.  While I can't find the original link, someone had already posted the critical xrandr arguments for the 2010 iMac with the Radeon HD 4670.  Building on that, below is the solution that worked for me.  Hope it helps others.

I let the iMac fully boot up, hit the enter key once to select the default login I couldn't see and typed my password.  Next, I typed Ctrl+Alt+t to open Terminal.  Of course, I was still running blind so I hit the backspace key to confirm the terminal was open.  A backspace in terminal will chime. Next I typed:

```
xrandr -d $DISPLAY --output eDP --crtc 1
```

Out of the darkness, my desktop appeared.

In order to allow xrandr to work with GDM3, I had to disable Wayland by
uncommenting WaylandEnable=false in /etc/gdm3/custom.conf.

Next, I created a bash script, /usr/local/bin/fix_display, with the xrandr command above.

```
printf '%s\n' '#!/bin/bash' 'xrandr -d $DISPLAY --output eDP --crtc 1' | sudo tee /usr/local/bin/fix_display

sudo chmod 755 /usr/local/bin/fix_display
```

Calling the fix_diplay script from /etc/gdm3/Init/Default didn't work, likely due to the reported bugs with GDM3 not actually calling the Init/Default script.  So I searched for other solutions. Journalctl showed that /etc/gdm3/Prime/Default was getting called so I edited /etc/gdm3/Prime/Default to call /usr/local/bin/fix_display which allowed the xrandr command to be run when GDM3 starts.

Finally, I edited ~/.xsessionrc to call /usr/local/bin/fix_display so that I didn't have to blindly open a terminal and type the command on each login.

```
echo /usr/local/bin/fix_display >> ~/.xsessionrc
```

I rebooted and had a working internal display for X11.

Now when rebooting the screen initially goes black but comes back once GDM3 starts.  When logging in, again the screen goes black for a moment and then comes back when .xsessionrc runs.  Note, GDM3 runs on display :0 and each concurrent user increments from there... so the first user ends up on display :1, the second concurrent user on :2, etc.

Ultimately, I've been unable to translate the xrandr command arguments above into a working Xorg config file so I'll continue with this workaround.

And while we're talking about the 2010 iMac, if you use mbpfan to control your fan speeds, make sure you add all three fan speeds to the conf file.  My iMac ran a bit hot and I think I just lost the LED Driver Board as my backlight is dead.  A new darkness to overcome...

Answer (score -1):

I'm going through this process and have exactly the same hardware as you. The only difference is that I am booting from a live USB and not DVD. When the GRUB menu shows you need to press <kbd>E</kbd> and modify the command line by adding `nomodeset`, then it will start with graphic interface. Once installed, you then need to change your GRUB config to make this permanent.